# Plot data in website from multiple csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, fetch-api

I made a static website hosted on an AWS s3 bucket.

I do not know the tools and technology around web development, but I took an example of **index.html** code allowing me to plot data from a single file named "my_data_file1.csv".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Coding Train: Data and APIs Project 1</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Global Temperatures</h1>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>

    <script>

      window.addEventListener('load', setup);

      async function setup() {
        const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        const globalTemps = await getData();
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
            labels: globalTemps.years,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: 'Temperature in °C',
                data: globalTemps.temps,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
                borderWidth: 1
              }
            ]
          },
          options: {}
        });
      }

      async function getData() {
        const response = await fetch('my_data_file1.csv');
        const data = await response.text();
        const years = [];
        const temps = [];
        const rows = data.split('\n').slice(1);
        rows.forEach(row => {
          const cols = row.split(',');
          years.push(cols[0]);
          temps.push(parseFloat(cols[2]));
        });
        return { years, temps };
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

All of my data is split into multiple files, so I would like to be able to account for all the CSV files in a directory, rather than just one. The name of my files is variable, so I cannot list them one by one.
Is it possible to use a filter or RegEx as "***.csv**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a filter or RegEx as "*.csv"?

No.

While URLs can be *generated* by mapping files and directories from a filesystem to URLs, a URL isn't a directory.

There is no way to [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) URLs.

---

You could ensure that the server, when asked for `./` returns a list of URLs and then parse and filter it with client-side JS, and then request each of those URLs (probably using `Promise.all` to determine when you had a response for every one of those requests).

You could also write server-side code to concatenate all the CSV data so you only have to make one request.

Comment: That's what I feared...Thanks you @Quentin